# Azure B2C: How to show a static HTML page only?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am modifying an existing custom policy's behavior and have not yet been able to find guidance on what I a trying to do.

### Backgound

I have a custom signup/signin policy with a terms & conditions page. The general workflow is:

- Sign up / Sign in
- Terms & conditions acceptance
- Send the claims back to the web application, which signs the user in

### Goal

I have been asked to modify the policy so that rather than redirecting back to the web application on sign in, it displays a custom HTML "pending verification page".

### What I've done

- Created and deployed the custom HTML content.
- Created a `ContentDefinition` that points to that HTML page:

```xml
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.pendingverification">
        <LoadUri>[redacted]/pending-verification.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Pending Verification</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

- Created a `TechnicalProfile` that uses that content definition:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-PendingVerification">
          <DisplayName>Pending Verification</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.pendingverification</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

- Added an `OrchestrationStep` that references the `TechnicalProfile`:

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ShowPendingVerificationPage" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-PendingVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

- Doublechecked that the order of the steps is what I'd expect and no steps are sharing the same order number in the orchestration.

### Challenge

Despite these steps, the pending verification page seems to be skipped each time, and the next step (which returns the claims) appears to be executed.

### Question

- Is my understanding of how to create and refer to a static page above correct?
- Is a technical profile with no input or output claims skipped by default?
- What is the correct way to show a static HTML file in this manner without continuing on to the next step in the orchestration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. A `ClaimsExchange` Orchestration Step will be skipped if there are no claims specified.

Of the examples I have seen, many people achieve this with a Claim that has a `UserInputType` of `Readonly`.

I am not aware of anything else, sans a more complicated Javascript to move content in and out.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Just before reading your answer, I came to the conclusion that the more property way to approach this is to implement a challenge step based on a claim. The ultimate business goal I had, which I should have articulated more clearly, is to block users who are not yet verified (which is determined by an existing claim.) Thank you for your diligent answers on my questions recently!

Comment: My pleasure. I've found that I have needed to get a bit more "creative" when dealing with things in the Identity Trust Framework.

Comment: Thanks @SeanKilleen and as mentioned Claim that has a UserInputType of Readonly can able to make static page is working. Please let us know if you need more help.

Comment: @SeanKilleen, Hello, im facing the same requirement, did you managed to make it work? do you have a live working sample?